# Mystery text message connected to a Chinese news site?

Tags: iphone

Over the past few weeks I have noticed that there is a mystery contact showing up in my text message history:

[image]

When I click into this message there is nothing in the history.  I went to the domain associated with the text message and found the Chinese news site: hxxp://21cn.com/.  I've noticed that the day associated with the text ("Monday" in the image above) will update once a week or so.

Has anyone heard of anything like this?  Has my phone been compromised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, the domain 21cn.com has been compromised and is being used to send spam. Bear in mind that spam does not always have to have a message body and can many times be sent from an unsuspecting victim accounts that were not secured properly or suffered a breach of any kind.

In regards to the date changing, that may be because of a new message being sent. Apple has odd quirks when sending 'iMessages'. For instance, I can open up iMessenger on my macbook and send a 'blank' text from my account to anyone (by simply pressing return).

Alternatively, this could be the result of some sophisticated virus (or perhaps a simple bug with IOS). I find the virus assumption unlikely, but it is still theoretically possible.

I would just delete it and perhaps block that contact (pubdma@21cn.com) and perhaps [report the spam](http://www.justice.gov/spam.htm)